# python auto restarting script

Tags: python

I need script which starts itself at the end of process.
I use this code but it wait for execfile. How to run it async? To do the effect of script restarting.

```
import time
print "start"
time.sleep(5)
print "go exec"
execfile('res.py')
print "stop exec"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a program asynchronously from Python, you can use the Popen function as shown [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family):

```
import subprocess
# ...
pid = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python2.7", "res.py"]).pid
```

That said, if you are invoking something over and over again, you probably want to use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (all UNIX variants, including Linux and Mac OS X) or [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) (Mac OS X). You can create a cron job by invoking the command `crontab -e` and then adding a line such as the following (the asterisks below mean "each" and correspond to minutes, hours, days of the month, months, and days of the week):

```
*    *    *    *    *    /usr/bin/python2.7  script_to_execute.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The line above will run "script_to_execute.py" every minute. You can see some of the examples on the [cron Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for specifying different intervals at which a script should run.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many [os.exec...](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management) functions (on Unix-y systems, including e.g. Linux and Mac, and also on Windows) may be what you want.  You'll need to execute the [sys.executable](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable) (that's the `.exe` -- or equivalent executable file on non-Windows OSs -- with the Python version currently in use) with (roughly) the same arguments as are listed in `sys.argv` (though there may be a bit more work if you also need to reproduce some Python command-line flags, such as e.g. `-u` for unbuffered std I/O).